# connect to remote cassandra JMX by jolokia proxy

Tags: cassandra, jmx, jolokia

I try to connect to remote cassandra JMX by jolokia ([jolokia site](https://jolokia.org/)) proxy and hawt ([hawt site](http://hawt.io/)) programs but i can't. please guide me which configs and changes is needed in jolokia and hatw programs.

Comment: did you check firewall settings, also try to setup the whole process locally first. Then see if you even can access the remote ports from where you want to access the jmx. It looks to me you are facing some sort of networking issue. Also please provide any exceptions and logs that you may already have.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb here, and suggest that you have not enabled remote JMX in the cassandra configuration. According to the [datastax documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/secureJmxAuthentication.html?hl=remote%2Cjmx), you should edit cassandra-env.sh and enable remote_jmx (set `$LOCAL_JMX = no`) and edit these lines to suit your needs:

```
LOCAL_JMX=no

if [ "$LOCAL_JMX" = "yes" ]; then
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.jmx.local.port=$JMX_PORT -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
else
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$JMX_PORT"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=$JMX_PORT"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/etc/cassandra/jmxremote.password"
#  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/keystore"
#  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=<keystore-password>"
#  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/truststore"
#  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<truststore-password>"
#  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.need.client.auth=true"
#  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.registry.ssl=true"
#  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.enabled.protocols=<enabled-protocols>"
#  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.enabled.cipher.suites=<enabled-cipher-suites>"
fi
```